# Есть ли аналог datalist? (input с поиском плюс select)

Tags: jquery, select, input

Chosen и подобные не подходят, т.к. если в списке не найдено совпадений, то введенный текст не сохраняется.

Желательно в оформлении bootstrap, если есть такие.

Вот по типу этого, но только чтоб то что мы ввели оставалось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если не найдено, текст не сохраняется. Нужно чтоб оставался в инпуте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/

Answer (score 1):

Есть подобная возможность у selectize.js: https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

```
                <div class="sandbox">
                    <label for="select-beast">Beast:</label>
                    <select id="select-beast" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select a person...">
                        <option value="">Select a person...</option>
                        <option value="1">Chuck Testa</option>
                        <option value="4">Sage Cattabriga-Alosa</option>
                        <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    The most vanilla of examples.
                </div>
                <script class="show">
                $('#select-beast').selectize({
                    create: true,
                    sortField: 'text'
                });
                </script>
```

Comment: В ваш ответ так и напрашивается фрагмент кода. Пока это т.н. "ответ-ссылка", который обычно преобразуют в комментарии или сразу оформляют как комментарии.